# Why does in_array() not work on $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays, post, isset

I'm trying to check that user's submitted data, from `$_POST`, has at least the same elements that my passed array has. I'm doing it because I will use those elements later by calling `$_POST['element']` and I don't like errors about that element doesn't exist (isn't set). :)

I don't want to use something like `isset($_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['z'])` because each time I need to rewrite `$_POST` and it seems unreadable as well.

I tried to use `in_array(array('x', 'y', 'z'), $_POST)`, but it doesn't work (it returns `false` when it should return `true`). Any ideas how to make that work? :) I'm sure that I have empty strings as `$_POST['x']`, `$_POST['y']` and `$_POST['z']`. I even tried to change values of hose three `$_POST` elements to something other than empty string - still... doesn'y work as expected. :(

Thanks in an advice! :)

**Edit:**

Just found out that `in_array()` checks values, not keys. Then, I tried to do like this...

`in_array(array('title', 'slug', 'content'), array_keys($_POST))`

Still, it returns `false`. How does it comes so?  ;/

**Edit #2:**

Okay, here are results of debugging...

Incoming `$_POST`:

```
array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["slug"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    string(0) ""
}
```

Result of `array_keys($_POST)`:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "title"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "slug"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "content"
}
```

Result of `in_array(array('title', 'slug', 'content'), array_keys($_POST))`:

```
bool(false)
```

The question... why is it `false`? I did all correct, as much as I know.

**Edit #3:**

At the end, I created my own method called [`Arr::keys_exists($keys, $array)`](https://gist.github.com/1272557).

Comment: did you try to print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: See 'Edit #2' for results of debugging.

Comment: in_array can only test a value at a time in_array('title', $array_keys) will work. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`in_array()` checks to see if a *value* exists in an array, not a *key*. If you want to check to see if a key exists, then you'd want something like...

```
in_array('x', array_keys($_POST));
```

or the simpler...

```
array_key_exists('x', $_POST);
```

---

If you want to check for many keys at once:

```
$required_keys = array('x'=>1, 'y'=>1, 'z'=>1);
$missing_keys = array_diff_key($required_keys, $_POST);
$missing_keys_count = count($missing_keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) checks if the needle is in the array exactly. See example #3 of the manual-page. [`array_key_exists`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) cannot work with a key as first argument because array's aren't valid with arrays as keys.

You want something like `all_in_array(array $needles, array $haystack);` or `array_all_keys_exists(array $keys, array $search);` which returns whether all elements are in the array. You can probably implement something like this yourself, or ask for more help here.

Comment: So... I need to create my custom function that checks that keys are in 'master' array one by one, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you think it'll make your program easier to understand/cleaner than using isset($_POST['key1'], $_POST['key2'], etc...);

Comment: Take a look at 'Edit #3'. I created my own method for it. :)

Comment: Looks fine. You don't _have_ to use strict `===` checking, because array_key_exists only return true or false. But there's noting wrong with it.

Comment: I'm using strict type-checking only because that function returns **only** boolean. Looks more clearer to me! :)

Answer (score 0):

> in_array(array('x', 'y', 'z'), $_POST), but it doesn't work (it returns false when it should return true)

No, it shouldn't. Read the manual of [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

> Checks if a **value** exists in an array

Instead you'd like to check array keys. Get all the keys with [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and then use in_array.

With in_array you can test only one value at a time, though, not a whole array of values like you're trying to do.

In other words, if you do:

```
in_array(array('title', 'slug', 'content'), array_keys($_POST))
```

It will to find **one element** of the keys array containing an array with title, slug and comment, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

> I don't want to use something like isset($_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['z']) because each time I need to rewrite $_POST and it seems unreadable as well.

You should never change one of the super globals ;)

However, `in_array()` searches for values and not for keys

```
in_array(array('x', 'y', 'z'), array_key($_POST))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPost( $index, $default = '' )
{
    if ( isset( $_POST[ $index ] ) )
    {
        return $_POST[ $index ];
    }

    return $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the presence of multiple keys, then [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) might be applicable:

```
!array_diff(array('title', 'slug', 'content'), array_keys($_POST))
```

You might also be interested in [`array_intersect_uassoc`](http://php.net/array_intersect_uassoc).

Answer (score 0):

@Eric was right, try this -

```
in_array(array('title', 'slug', 'content'), array(array_keys($_POST)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't understand [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$a = array(
    'x' => 1
);
echo in_array(array('x', 'y', 'z'), $a); // false

$a['an array'] = array('x', 'y', 'z');
echo in_array(array('x', 'y', 'z'), $a); // true
```

Comment: That was the first thing I thought when I noticed that my code doesn't work as expected. This means that I need to create my custom method for it.